# reportviewer parameters

Tags: .net, winforms, reportviewer

I have a winform with a datefield. When a user selects a date and submits, a reportviewer on the page takes the date as a parameter through the tableadapter and shows the report.

What I need is a way to print the user selected date on the report.

Can someone show me how to pass a value from the winform to the rdlc file and make it print on the report itself?

I assume I would use a report parameter, but I can't seem to find any good documentation on how to accomplish this. 
thanks.

Answer (score 1):

Check [Report Parameters (ReportViewer Controls)](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms251750(VS.80).aspx) and one suggestion, visit MSDN when you need some references, because if you do it you will learn more and better. ;)

Answer (score 0):

You can do something like this:

```
IList<ReportParameter> parameters = new List<ReportParameter>();
parameters.Add(new ReportParameter("MyDate", "1/1/2011"));
viewer.LocalReport.SetParameters(parameters);     
viewer.RefreshReport();
```

The name of the parameter (MyDate above) must matches the name with wich you have defined the parameter in the report designer.